# Laravel 4.2: After checking “remember me” checkbox user's login doesn't get remembered in database, only in cookie, thus remember me not working

Tags: php, authentication, cookies, laravel-4

I am using laravel 4.2

I have a login form where I am trying to implement the remember me functionality. I have used Auth::attempt() to implement the above. Here's my code.

```
        public function logintest()
        {

            // set the remember me cookie if the user check the box
            $remember = (Input::has('remember')) ? true : false;

            // attempt to do the login
            $auth=Auth::attempt(
            [
                'username'  => Input::get('username'),
                'password'  => put::get('password')                      
            ], $remember);

          if ($auth)
            {
                // The user is active, not suspended, and exists.
                $id = Auth::user()->id;
                return Redirect::to("example/$id");
            }
            else
            {
                return Redirect::to('example')
                ->with('flash_error', 'Incorrect Username or Password!');
            }
         }
```

I have also created a column "remember_token"(a nullable string with 255 chars) in registration table. And also added below 3 methods in the model MyModel.php

```
   public function getRememberToken()
   {
            return $this->remember_token;
   }

   public function setRememberToken($value)
   {
           $this->remember_token = $value;
   }

   public function getRememberTokenName()
   {
           return 'remember_token';
   }
```

Yes it does sets the cookie named remember_xxxxxx, but it doesn't add anything to the remember_token column. It's not working. Is there something i missed ?

Comment: Is the remember_token in the ````private $fillable```` var? not sure that exists in 4.2.  And you should store the functions in the User model.

Comment: I didnt get you.sorry.I am absolutely new to laravel.pls make it clear :(

Comment: I added the code 
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');
in MyModel.Now remember_token is storing in register table.But the username and password is not remembering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please notice that remember_token only makes sure that the user won't be logged out after 2 hours (or any other amount of time that has been given in the config file).

You need to have a user model before it will work.
The fillable variable tells the model which fields may be mass assigned (changed).

```
class Users extends Eloquent {

    protected $fillable = array('username', 'password', 'remember_token');

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return 'remember_token';
    }
}
```

This name of the model needs to have the exact same name as the table in the database or you can specify the table name in a variable called table. I think you want to store the remember_token in the same table as where the users are.

In the controller you should add

```
use Location\To\Model;
```

So assuming you created a Model directory inside the app directory

```
use App\Model\Users;
```

To authenticate users by their remember token you should use

```
if (Auth::viaRemember())
{
    //
}
```

Comment: I have User Model.But i didnt used it.I created my own model.Is it compulsory to use User Model for implementing Auth?

Comment: @MeenuAM The name of the model should be the name of the table as eloquent tries to find the table name with the same name as the class. I would suggest moving everything back to the user model

Comment: I added the code    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');         in MyModel.MyModel is now exaclty looks like User Model.Now remember_token is storing in register table.But the username and password is not remembering .What to do???

Comment: @MeenuAM So the token is stored now? You only have a problem with authenticating? A btw remember_token only makes sure you do not logout from the website after 2 hours the part that really keeps your user data in the input fields after loging out is the browser with their cookies

Comment: Actually I dont know the effect of remember me.I am trying to get the username and password automatically in tha login form once we check remember me option.Cookie is setting and remember_token is storing in database.But the username and password is not coming automatically

Comment: @MeenuAM Ah yea i had exactly the same thing when i added this functionality to my own website! I was expecting that too but this does something else. I don't know the way of doing that i think a user should click on the store my user data request of the browser. The only thing that remember_token does is make sure you don't log out automaticaly after 2 hours

Comment: OK Thank you so much.
Now I am going to try forgot password option. :)